# How to trigger automated test from TestRail using a combination of a UI script and custom server-side scripts

Tags: selenium, automation, testrail

Most teams who integrate their automated tests with TestRail trigger and execute their automated tests outside of TestRail (e.g. as part of a continuous integration system) and use TestRail's API to submit the test results.

but I want to trigger automated test from TestRail using a combination of a UI script and custom server-side scripts.

How can we do this?

Please find this link for more details.
http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-custom/automation-trigger

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not yet but I am sure there is some solution. Kindly help if you know.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to trigger automated tests via a UI script in TestRail.
But I found it is not provided for TestRail(5.x) yet,check more details below link.
http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-custom/automation-trigger

Also as per my search on this I found it doesn't provide very many benefits and better approach is triggering your automated tests outside of TestRail either manually or via a continuous integration system. You can use TestRail API to submit the test results to TestRail, and this is the best and recommended approach I found.
Thanks.

Comment: the link arent available !